# storing files to aws s3 using laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3, laravel-5.5, laravel-filesystem

Please give me an example to store files to AWS S3 in laravel 5.5.
I already configured filesystem file with AWS credentials.

I saw the function

`Storage::put('file.jpg', $contents);`

but don't know what the second parameter is

the contents of filesystem.php file is as follows

```
return [


    'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),



    'cloud' => env('FILESYSTEM_CLOUD', 's3'),


    'disks' => [

        'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],

        's3' => [
            'driver' => 's3',
            'key' => '*********',
            'secret' => '******',
            'region' => 'my region',
            'bucket' => 'bucketname',
        ],

    ],

];
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Show us  content of your `filesystems.php`

Comment: The second parameter is the actual raw contents of the file (a string) or it's a PHP resource (e.g. a file stream handle). The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem) does say that.

Comment: updated filesystem contents in question, can you please give me an example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is good example in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#obtaining-disk-instances):

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('avatars/1', $fileContents);
```

The 2nd parameter is is file content so in real life it could look like this:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put('file.jpg', file_get_contents('your_local_file.jpg');
```